# Eclipse Plugin development: How to jump to Marker in the Source View from Problems View?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently developing an editor for my own language. I add error Marker to my Source View with this code:

```
private void displayError(Interval interval, String message) {
    int startIndex = interval.a;
    int stopIndex = interval.b + 1;
    Annotation annotation =
        new Annotation("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error", false, message);
    annotations.add(annotation);
    annotationModel.addAnnotation(annotation, new Position(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex));
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(); 
    IMarker marker;
    try { //create Marker to display Syntax Errors in Problems View
        marker = workspace.getRoot().createMarker(MARKERID);

        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, message);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, startIndex);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, stopIndex);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        //marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION, workspace.getRoot().getLocationURI().toString());
        MarkerUtilities.setCharStart(marker, startIndex);
        MarkerUtilities.setCharEnd(marker, stopIndex);
        int lineNumber = 0;
        if(!content.isEmpty() && content.length()>=stopIndex){  //Convert StartIndex to Line Number
            String[] lines = content.substring(0, stopIndex).split("\r\n|\r|\n");
            lineNumber = lines.length;
        }
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.TEXT, message);
        marker.setAttribute(IDE.EDITOR_ID_ATTR, "de.se_rwth.langeditor");
        MarkerAnnotation ma = new MarkerAnnotation("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error", marker);
        annotationModel.addAnnotation(ma, new Position(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex));
        annotations.add(ma);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

The Marker are correctly displayed in the Problems View. Bt if I double click on the Problem Marker it won't jump to the correct position in the code. Also if I right click on the Problem Marker, the Option "Go to" is disabled. My Editor class, which extends the TextEditor, also implements the IGotoMarker Interface. The gotoMarker method is implemented by me like this:

```
public void gotoMarker(IMarker marker) {
        IDE.gotoMarker(this, marker);
    }
```

The getAdapter Method looks like this:

```
public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
      if (IContentOutlinePage.class.equals(adapter)) {
      return contentOutlinePage;
    }
    return super.getAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

It would be great, if someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the marker on the workspace root resource with:

```
marker = workspace.getRoot().createMarker(MARKERID);
```

This is wrong, you must create the marker on the actual `IFile` that you are editing.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Now it displays every error twice in the problems view. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Not sure, but remember that markers are permanent, you may need to use `IResource.deleteMarkers` to delete old markers.